# Rails testing multiple belongs to model using fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models. `Question` , `Answer` and `ReceivedAnswer`.

Question contains question.
Answer contains valid answer for that particular question
Received Answer contain answer provided by participants. It must be one of the valid answers and it also contains some data related to participants

Following are the relationships:

Question has many answers and received answers.
Answer belongs to Question
Received Answer belongs to Question and Answer

received_answer.rb

```
class ReceivedAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :question

end
```

I have created the following fixtures

questions.yml

```
one:
    text: Hello World
```

answers.yml

```
answer_one:
  answer_option: A
  answer_text: Football
```

The setup for AnswerTest

```
    def setup
        @question = questions(:one)
        @answer = @question.answers.build(answer_text: 'Hello World')
    end
```

which works perfectly fine.

How should I setup for Received Answer ?
I have tried the following:

```
 def setup
    @answer = answers(:answer_one)
    @received_answer = @answer.question.received_answers.build(phone_number: 'phone 1')
  end
```

I have following questions:

- Is the schema correct ?
- Received Answer should be built using which    model and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a real example.

First, a question, and the desired answer options:

**Question**: How many years of experience do you have with Rails?

**Answer options**:

- No experience whatsoever
- < 1 year
- 1 - 3 years
- 3 - 5 years
- > 5 years

Some responses:

### number  | name | experience

1. | Experienced Coder | > 5 years
2. | First Coder | 1 - 3 years
3. | Second Coder | 1 - 3 years
4. | Newbie Coder | < 1 year
5. | Java Coder | No experience whatsoever

...

So each question has some answer choices, and a few responses.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answer_choices
  has_many :responses
end
```

Each answer choice belongs to a question.

```
class AnswerChoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Each response belongs to a question, and a user.

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end
```

There is no belongs_to relationship between `answer_choice` and `response`. There is however a restriction that the values in the responses for a question be limited to the the related answer choices. This is not a restriction to be handled at the model level, but at the view level when the possible answer choices are being displayed for the question while someone is answering the question.

Fixtures:

```
# questions.yml
one:
  text: Hello World

# answer_choices.yml
one:
  question: one # This would associate answer_choice_one to questions(:one)
  answer_option: A
  answer_text: Football
two:
  question: one # This would associate answer_choice_one to questions(:one)
  answer_option: B
  answer_text: Soccer

# responses.yml
one:
  user: one  # This would associate response_one to users(:one)
  question: one # This would associate response_one to questions(:one)
  answer_text: Football # There is no association here, but picking a value in the answer_choices fixture.

# users.yml
one:
  name: First Person
```

Setup for testing:

```
def setup
   @question = questions(:one)
   @answer_choice_one = answer_choices(:one)
   @answer_choice_two = answer_choices(:two)

   @user = users(:one)
   @first_response = responses(:one)
end

test '.... ' do
  assert_equal @first_response.answer_text, @answer_choice_one.answer_text
end
```

On a different note, multiple belongs_to relationships are valid, and can be tested with fixtures in the same manner as above where answer_choice/response is related to questions. Do check out the detail about working with associations in [The Low-down on Fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures) section of rails guides.

Comment: Thanks. It was 'question: one' that I was looking for.